# Standard library ABI compatibility

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

Suppose we have a shared library which accepts or returns some kind of std class:

```
//lib.h
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> returnSomeInts();

//lib.cpp
#include "lib.cpp"

std::vector<int> returnSomeInts() {
   return {1, 3, 5};
}
```

So, obviously, when compiling the shared library `lib.so`, this code had to be compiled against a particular version of the standard library, for instance with -std=c++11.

Now imagine we have an application which will be using our shared library, but it will be compiled against a newer std library, for example -std=c++2a

```
//app.cpp
#include <lib.h>

int main()
   auto v = returnSomeInts();

   //Process v
}
```

As the standard library defines inline classes, if the layout of the class members changes, ABI compatibility gets broken, so the code above would not work properly.

My questions are: Is there any guarantee for ABI stability with the common implementations of the the std library when compiling against the same header using different c++ standards? And when compiling against different header versions (libstdc++-8 and libstdc++-9 for example)?

PD: The code above is just an example, I am not referring specifically to `std::vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ABIs in practice are not linked to the standard, for example consider this following code [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/-Kq8Si) with gcc 4.9.4 and gcc 5.1
using the same flags:

> -std=c++11 -O2

```
#include <string>
int main(){
    return sizeof (std::string);
}
```

gcc 4.9.4 returns 8 from main, gcc 5.1 returns 32.

As for guarantees: it is complicated:

Nothing is guaranteed by the standard.

Practically MSVC used to break ABI compatability, they stopped (v140,v141,v142 use the same ABI), clang/gcc have a stable ABI for a long time.

For those interested in learning more:
For a broad discussion of ABI/C++ standard that is not directly related to this question you an look at this [blog](https://cor3ntin.github.io/posts/abi/) post.

Answer (score 2):

Your example with `std::vector` is not a problem. As other answer points out compilers maintain compatibility and `std::vector` is quite old.

Problem can be new library features of newer C++ standard is used.

For example I have some product which uses C++17 languages features. My product supports MacOS 10.13. I can build my project using C++17 (language features), but I can't use for example [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) since some methods are throwing [std::bad_optional_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/bad_optional_access) which is part dynamic library and this is not supported/present in MacOS 10.13. Clang warns me about that (reports an error).

Same applies on other system (clang nicely controls that). So when you use some library features you need make sure that libraries on deployed system supports that (on Linux package managers handle that nicely if system doesn't have access to required package version installation will fail). On Windows 10 AFAIK Windows update keeps newest version of msvc redistributable, older versions of Windows need manual updates.

Note that many templates are becoming part of your executable and do not have dependencies to shared standard library. Those will not create problems.

Answer (score 1):

These are the kinds of question that the standard doesn't answer, it is down to individual implementers how long they keep compatibility for and which (if any) compiler flags affect compatibility.

In practice libstdc++ on Linux has tried very hard to keep a stable ABI for quite a long time now. The soversion has remained at 6 for around 15 years now.

However there have been some changes, most notable were those introduced with g++-5.1 related to std::list and std::string. New requirements in c++11 meant that to be compliant libstdc++ needed to make breaking changes to the ABI of those classes.

g++'s solution was to define two versions of those classes. To allow both types to coexist in the same shared library they are defined with different names, so the old std::list is defined as std::list while the new std::list is defined as std::__cxx11::list and then aliased as std::list. Which definition is used in a given source file is controlled by a preprocessor macro.

Note that the setting of said preprocessor macro is independent of the -std= setting, you can use the compiler in c++11 mode with the old string/list implementation (in which case it won't be fully compliant with the standard) or you can use the compiler in c++03 mode with the new string/list implementations.

The default value of the macro (if not set explicitly by the user) depends on compiler version and can also be overridden by distribution maintainers.

The trouble is while this solves the problem for libstdc++ it doesn't solve it for all the other libraries. If a program was built with the new implementations while a library was built with the old ones or vice-versa and the library used std::string or std::list in it's API, then the likely outcome was a link failure (it was also possible but less-likely for the linking to succeed but the program to be silently broken). In Debian at least this lead to a massive set of library transitions (it would not surprise me if it was the largest in the project's entire history).