# build project with multi g++ versions

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++14

I have a project which consists of many libraries. I wrote the code based on g++20 but a library supports up to g++14. the library can be imported using cmake's `add_subdirectory`. Is there any way to compile this library with g++14 but everything else with g++20?

Comment: First thing to check is: does g++ (and the C++ runtime support library) support linking together libraries built with different version of the Standard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard library ABI compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836246/standard-library-abi-compatibility)

Comment: Yes thanks to both of you